# Why `conda update conda` updates a whole lot of other packages?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I ran `conda update conda` and the prompt came back asking to download and update several other packages, like for example:

- `pandas` from `1.4.3` to `1.5.3`
- `numba` from `0.55.2` to `0.56.4`
- `dask` from `2022.7` to `2023.1`

and lots of other packages, too many to mention. `Conda` itself, is currently at `22.9.0` and will be updated to `22.11.1`.

I thought `conda update conda` updates conda, the package/environment manager, to the latest version. Why does it want to update individual packages in my env?

Edit: The actual output, following Merv's comment, is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dw3i87wk6qfgunr/conda.log?dl=0)

Comment: I don't work with conda, but have you checked what dependencies does conda have? When you update one package, its dependencies are also checked for the best matching versions. And then those dependencies may have their own dependencies - thus making it a quite big update.

Comment: Please show the actual output, not a selective summary; otherwise you are potentially hiding important clues. For instance, editing channel priorities often leads to unexpected package changes. Conda is also aggressive at updating some security packages, and if those have any conflicts, it can trigger a full resolve - making everything fair game. But would need more info to be precise.

Answer (score 1):

Running `conda update` applies a more holistic update approach to your environment. If you only want to update the package specified, include the `--no-update-deps` argument (see [solver modifiers](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/update.html#Solver%20Mode%20Modifiers)):

```
conda update -n base --no-update-deps conda
```

And from the [help blurb/docs for `conda update`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/update.html):

> This may force conda to install older versions of the requested packages, and it does not prevent additional dependency packages from being installed.